Integrating a smooth 1-form over shrinking loops in the complex plane is independent of the shrinking loops family in the limit?
Let $U \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ be an open subset with $U \ni 0$, let $\varphi \in C^\infty(U,\mathbb{C})$, and consider the smooth $1$-form $\omega := \varphi(z) \frac{dz}{z}$ on $U \setminus \{0\}$. If $\gamma_\varepsilon(t) := \varepsilon e^{2\pi i t}$, $t \in [0,1]$, is a family of loops in $U \setminus \{0\}$ (for $\varepsilon > 0$ sufficiently small), then it is easy to show by direct computation that
$$
\varphi(0) = \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \oint_{\gamma_\varepsilon} \omega
$$
This is part of the usual proof of the Cauchy-Pompeiu formula.

Can one show this identity for a more general, abstract family of loops $\gamma_\varepsilon$ that "shrink" to the point $0 \in U$ (possibly under some additional conditions making "shrinking to a point" precise)?

PS: I am actually interested in doing this procedure over smooth surfaces, but I realized that I don't know the answer in this generality for the simplest case of a plane.

The technical name for  the process of shrinking or deforming one loop to another is called a homotopy. So you should look for discussions of the Homotopy Version of the Cauchy Integral Formula. In a quick web search I found this item: https://faculty.etsu.edu/gardnerr/5510/notes/IV-6.pdf

@MathFont: Thanks, I am fully aware of what homotopy is, that's not what I am asking, though. Since $\varphi(z)$ is only smooth (rather than holomorphic), the 1-form $\omega$ is in general not closed, so $\oint \omega$ won't be "invariant" under homotopy. (And indeed, if it were, we wouldn't be needing to take the limit as $\varepsilon \to 0$.) But I suspect that the integral is so to speak "homotopy invariant in the limit", which is what my question is about.

If $\phi(z)$ is merely assumed to have the property that its real and imaginary parts are real-differentiable at the origin then we can expand it  near the origin as $\phi(z)=\phi(0)+ A z + B \overline z + o(|z|)$
Thus
$$\oint_C \frac{ \phi(z) dz}{z} =2\pi i \phi(0) + \oint_C A dz + B \oint_C \frac{ \overline z\  dz}{z}  +\int_C \frac{o(|z|)}{z}dz$$
Of course $\oint_C A dz=0$.
The integral $\oint_C \frac{ \overline z\  dz}{z}$ is majorized by $\oint_C |dz| =|C|=$ Total length of $C$.
Finally,  $|\int_C \frac{o(|z|)}{z}dz|\leq \int_C |o(1) dz|$= $o(1) |C|$ is even smaller.
Thus your conjecture can be proved if the family of curves is reasonably well behaved,   in the sense that their lengths $|C|\to 0$.
Retrospective comments.

The coefficients $A$   and $B$ are sometimes called the  Wirtinger partial derivatives of $\phi$.

Another way to bound the integral $\oint_C \omega$ where $\omega=\frac{\overline z \ dz}{z}$ is to use the complex version of de Rham's theorem ( which is essentially just Green's Theorem.) Consider a very small circular path  $\Gamma$ around the origin, and let $D$ be the region between  the inner loop $\Gamma$ and the outer curvilinear loop $C$.


Then $\oint _C \omega - \oint_{\Gamma } \omega = \int\int_D d\omega =\int\int_D \frac{ d\overline z \ dz}{z} =\int \int _D 2i \frac{dx \ dy}{z} $ which after switching to polar coordinates becomes   $ 2i \int \int e^{-i \theta}  dr \ d\theta$.
This is bounded by $O(R_2- R_1)$ where these radii are the  outer and inner radii of an annulus that encloses $D$.
Also $\oint_{\Gamma} \omega =\oint_{\Gamma} e^{-2i\theta} d\theta =0$. Thus we see that it suffices to require $R_2\to 0$, which is a much weaker requirement than demanding that the length $|C|\to 0$.

This is exactly what I was looking for! Very nice, thanks!
